# Scanning encrypted drive

Tags: hard-drive, encryption, truecrypt

I have a TrueCrypt encrypted partition on a drive. I wanted to use Windows 7 disk checking tool to scan and fix folders/files on the encrypted partition, just like you would do on a regular (unencrypted) drive. What is the safest way to about this? When I try to scan the partition in mounted mode, I get prompt to unmount first. Scanning raw encrypted partition does not make sense to me.

Any thoughts or ideas? I am open to any disk scanning tool. My primary goal is to recover possible lost files/folders on the encrypted partition.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

One HDD scan/maintenance tool I've used is [SpinRite](http://www.grc.com) and the creator claims it doesn't care about the data it reads. It simply reads whether the bit is 1, or 0. So whether it is fully encrypted, or not, as long as they can read it as 1s and 0s it will be able to work with the HDD. And if it is having trouble reading whether it is 1s or 0s (without error correction) then it will do its work to recover that single bit and move on to the rest of the HDD.

Answer (score 0):

It looks as if Windows gets a bit confused about the fact that the partition is encrypted.

As long as your checking tool (whatever you use) wants to check logical (NTFS?) structures (files, folders, indices etc) it can and should do so on the mounted volume, i.e. 'from within'.

When the tool wants to start scanning sectors it's not very useful to do that from within. It will receive the unencrypted data from Truecrypt, which at that moment has already read the sectors so you're checking what has already been succesfully read.

So for real scanning on the sector level you should use a tool like Darius suggests. These tools read on a level 'below' the OS. They just process hard disk sectors and don't care (and can't repair) logical errors in the file system.

With these tools you will have to access the disk before the OS starts (even before Truecrypt kicks in). Spinrite does that by booting from a CD with an embedded copy of FreeDOS ;-) as its OS.

Best practice would be to first use a sector checking tool as just described, then check the logical file structure with something like CheckDisk from with in the OS.